# Design a solid semisphere in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to design a solid semi-sphere in three.js. So far, all I found online is how to design an open-ended convex semi-sphere. I do not want a convex semi-sphere. What I want is to design a solid and closed all around semi-sphere.

Answer (score 0):

After creating  an your  open-ended convex semi-sphere you can create a CircleGeometry and place it at the bottom of your semi-sphere.

Then you can merge the two grometries.

Have a look at the merge() method of [Geometry Class](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Geometry)

Comment: Thanks leota, I will try it out your way and also with CSG.